# Asynchronous Bluetooth device discovery in UWP using 32Feet Bluetooth library

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, bluetooth, 32feet

In my UWP app I'm creating a Bluetooth device search where it would scan and display a list of Bluetooth devices in range:

[image: Cool screenshot of my UI B^)]

I'm using in the [inthehand/32feet](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet) Bluetooth library and am having trouble implementing async device discovery. According to the Wiki:

> ## Asynchronous Device Discovery
>
> We have new support in version 3 for ‘live’ discovery that’s where the
> application can get notification of each in-range device as it is
> discovered, instead of just getting the list of device at completion
> (as was previously provided by the DiscoveryDevices and
> End-/BeginDiscoveryDevices methods). The new method is provided on
> class BluetoothComponent with events DiscoverDevicesProgress and
> DiscoverDevicesComplete and method DiscoverDevicesAsync.

Sadly, [according to this issue](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/issues/72), this method won't work on the newest version of the library I think because it doesn't work with UWP:

> peterfoot commented on Jul 3, 2020
>
> I'm currently looking at this as an enhancement. The old v3.x version of the library did introduce a Begin* End* async pattern which fitted with the Win32 Sockets approach at the time but this is no longer recommended and doesn't apply easily to other platforms.

https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/issues/72#issuecomment-653493127

So now I've reached a dead end, I want to be able to load devices into the list as they are discovered, but the library doesn't support this in UWP. I can see 2 ways forward from here:

- Switch to Winui3 which should provide access to Win32 APIs (I think, not exactly sure). But I'd rather not do this because I like using the Visual Studio designer and I've read that there are performance issues and missing features that still need to be fixed.
- Suck it up and have to wait ~10-20 seconds of loading while bluetooth devices are scanned for.

So my question is, is there any way I can asynchronously scan for Bluetooth devices and display them as they are discovered in UWP (preferably using the 32 Feet Bluetooth library)?

Thanks :)